# jni starter question

Tags: java, c, dll, java-native-interface, native-code

I started looking into JNI and from what I understand is that if a problem occurs with the loaded dll, the jvm is possible to terminate on the spot.
I.e. the process can not be protected e.g. like when catching an exception.
So if my understanding is correct, my question is if there is a standard approach/pattern for this situation when using jni.
Or to state it differently, are processes using jni designed in way to avoid these issues?
Or such problems are not expected to occur?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the JVM will just terminate which is one of the reasons why JNI code is really hard to debug. If you are using C++ code you can use exceptions and then map them to a Java exception which at least gives you some level of security but doesn't help with things like bad memory access etc.

From an architecture point of view I suggest to decouple you code from JNI as much as possible. Create a class / procedure structure that is entirely testable from C++/ C and let the JNI code do only all the conversion stuff. If the JVM then crashes you at least know where you have to look.

Comment: The first idea that I was thinking was placing the post, was spawning a new process to access the dll.This way the original process survives.But I am not sure if this is used as an appoach

Comment: Hm, but in that case you might as well not use JNI at all and switch to another way of inter process communication. I would only use JNI  if speed is the biggest issue (and then it doesn't make sense to put it in it's own process). It is a trade between speed and security.

Answer (score 1):

The principles are no different from any multi-threaded C application:

1. Always check all your input thoroughly.
2. Always free up temporary memory you allocated.
3. Make sure your functions are re-entrant.
4. Don't rely on undefined behaviour.

The Java virtual machine offers you no extra protection for your native code, if it fails or is leaking, your VM will fail or leak.

Comment: @Daff:The first idea that I was thinking was placing the post, was spawning a new process to access the dll.This way the original process survives.But I am not sure if this is used as an appoach

Comment: @user384706 Spawning a new process isn't without its risks though and it is unacceptably slow for most uses. Plus if you're starting an external process anyway, why not do it from pure Java?

Comment: The idea I was thinking that the native code would be used in specific cases that could not be done in java, the original process spawns a new process to access the dll i.e. and any results/messages would be send to the parent process. If something happens the second process dies but the original process which could do much more functionality (accessing a dll) is just one part, would still live. Am not sure if this is a approach used. May be is too much?

Comment: @user384706 It does sound like a bit too much but I don't know the exact situation. Isn't it easier to just compile that other process into an exe and just launch it from Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can have exactly the same spectrum of error handling in a JNI library as in anything else.

You can use try/catch. If you are on Windows, you can use SEH. If you are on Linux, you can call sigaction.

Still, if you mess up and there's a SIGSEGV, your JVM is probably toast whether you try to catch that signal or not.